# Include mpi.h in Clion

Tags: c++, c, cmake, clion

I am running linux (Debian) and I want to include the header `mpi.h` into my project. The `mpi.h` is located under `/usr/include/mpi` and running `mpiCC` and `mpirun` shows that it's installed. I couldn't find a clear tutorial.

Comment: Just [include the directory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/include_directories.html) in the build.

Answer (score 8):

You should add `include_directories(/usr/include/mpi/)` to your CMakeLists.txt and just include the header:

```
#include <mpi.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include the header file `mpi/mpi.h`

Like this

```
    #include<mpi/mpi.h>
```